# USING DATEADD IN DERIVED COLUMN TRANSFORMATION IN SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sas

I am trying to use DATEADD function in a derived column transformation but it seems the expression i am using is wrong.  Initially, i was using this in my SQL query which works fine but i want to use it now in a derived column so i can transform the date value before i bring it into my table.  Here is the sql i was using:

```
select DATEADD(day,myDate,'19600101') as NewDate from myTable
```

but i want to use it now in derived column so i am replacing the column and using this in the expression:

```
DATEADD("day", myDate, "19600101" )
```

Comment: That looks valid (assuming myDate is a column of int type). What error are you getting?

Comment: So you have a SAS dataset that you are using SAS to manipulate?  Why not use the SAS INTNX function INTNX("DAY",MYDATE,1)?

Comment: Please either elaborate on why this is tagged as `sas` or remove the tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, here is the fix:

instead of:

```
DATEADD("day", myDate, "19600101" )
```

try:

```
DATEADD("day", (DT_DBDATE)myDate, (DT_DBDATE)"19600101")
```

This will return a database datestamp, which can be cast back to a string if needed. In my case, I am converting from Epoch time (milliseconds since 1/1/1970), so I need this:

```
DATEADD("s",(DT_I8)[Index Time],(DT_DBTIME)"1/1/1970")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation for dateadd: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141719.aspx.  I am not sure what you are tryinmg to do with this expression.  If you wanted to add one day then it would be:

```
select DATEADD(d,1,myDate) as NewDate from myTable
```

If you wanted to subtract one day then it would be:

```
select DATEADD(d,-1,myDate) as NewDate from myTable
```

Please explain what you are trying to do.  I do not think the first arguement should be inside double quotes.  Also "day" is not allowed according to the remarks section in my link.

Comment: sorry i am not trying to subtract but i am getting these values from SAS server and SAS stores their date value as numeric, for example in SAS they have something like this: 18999 and when i convert that it means this in SQL 2012-01-07

Comment: There is no reference to SAS in your question.  Please change that.